# Two row multi column horizontal scroll grid with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I can do this when looping through items to add a div before and after every odd or even item but I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this with JUST CSS flex.

I would like to get rid of the .col div and just use CSS.

I need to either display one row with items scrolling horizontal or a two row with items scrolling horizontal.

The one row is for mobile screens and two row is for anything larger than mobile.

Here's a pen

https://codepen.io/modemlooper/pen/rXWaVK

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let html = "";

const device = "tablet";

items.map((item, index) => {
  html +=
    "tablet" === device && index % 2 === 0 ? '<div class="col">' : "";

  html += '<div class="slide"><div>' + item + "</div></div>";

  html += "tablet" === device && index % 2 !== 0 ? "</div>" : "";
});

var e = document.createElement("div");
e.className += " box";
e.innerHTML = html;
document.querySelector(".wrap").appendChild(e);
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slide>div {
  min-width: 218px;
  height: 178px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide:nth-child(odd)>div {
  background: red;
}

.slide:nth-child(even)>div {
  background: blue;
}

.col:nth-child(odd) .slide:nth-child(odd)>div {
  background: red;
}

.col:nth-child(even) .slide:nth-child(even)>div {
  background: red;
}

.col:nth-child(even) .slide:nth-child(odd)>div {
  background: blue;
}

.col:nth-child(odd) .slide:nth-child(even)>div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Is `height` of blocks static?

Comment: Yes they have a set width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should fit your needs. Using only `CSS`.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* DESKTOP */
@media  (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```